# Delete an order from Mongo instance running on AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, amazon-ec2, instance

There is an Mongo DB instance running on AWS so it is can be accessed only from terminal (I guess).

the table is called **orders**

to see what entries are in the table I'm using this command:

```
db.orders.find()
```

it returns a list of all orders. The problem comes when I want to delete one order. If entering in terminal `db.orders.` and than hit the **tab** it returns the list of all available commands.

One that I need I think it's `db.orders.deleteOne()` but I don't know what argument to send to it.

The order that must be deleted looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea1a1c48a0c055870168770"), "display_id" : "WOW" }
```

so I tried with in many ways like:

```
db.orders.deleteOne(5ea1a1c48a0c055870168770)
db.orders.deleteOne("5ea1a1c48a0c055870168770")
db.orders.deleteOne(_id: 5ea1a1c48a0c055870168770)
db.orders.deleteOne("_id": "5ea1a1c48a0c055870168770")
```

but none of the seem to work.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.orders.deleteOne( { "_id" : ObjectId("563237a41a4d68582c2509da") } );
```